# How does VBE immediate window handle literal numbers?

Tags: vba, vbe

Using the immediate window to do some debugging, I came across the following which I have simplified for the purpose of this question:

running this command:

```
?20000*2
```

produces an 'overflow' error. Let's assume this is because we haven't declared a data type, and VBE has assumed `Integer` - the result falls outside the boundaries of a signed integer and therefore an overflow occurs.

However if I run:

```
?39999+1
```

I get `40000` as expected.

Is this because I've initially started with a `Long` instead of an `Integer` (i.e. 20,000 vs 39,999)? And therefore memory is allocated based on the initial input data rather than the calculation result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's correct. VBA will take the largest of the input components and allocate memory for the results. Since both of the components in the first example are Int, that's all you get.

You can use a type declaration character to force the VBE to treat a number as a certain data type

```
?20000&*2
 40000 
?20000*2&
 40000
```

In both those examples, the & (Long type declaration character) forces the memory allocation to a Long. It doesn't matter if it's the first component or a later one. I think there are some operations that get forced into particular data types. Exponentiation is one of them.

```
?2^2^2^2^2^2
 4294967296 
?typename(2^2^2^2^2^2)
Double
```

Even though all the components are Integers, the results is a Double - even when it doesn't have to be

```
?typename(2^2)
Double
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thanks. I didn't think to try the type declarations and I didn't realise that certain operators would default to certain data types - so this was extremely informative!

Answer (score 5):

This implicit typing isn't limited to the Immediate Window. The same overflows can occur in your code:

```
Sub foo()

  Dim x As Long

  x = 20000 * 2 'Overflow error

End Sub
```

Also, when a `String` is implicitly cast to a numeric type, it's cast as a  `Double`:

```
?TypeName("123" + 6)
Double
```

Comment: @MacroMan - It's 2 separate operations - a multiplication, then an assignment.  Both of the operands are in the integer range, so it only allocates an integer return value.  It doesn't check whether the *assignment* overflows until after it has a result, but by that time it's already overflowed.

Comment: Jeez, say what you want about javascript but at least you know where you stand!